# A task was cancelled while displaying OAuth Card

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework

I am trying to implement bot azure AD Authentication in my project and I am new to OAuth 2.0 and trying to do AzureAD V1 authentication with the git hub sample i downloaded from https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication

I had provided **ConnectionName** in code and trying to debug in emulator. I am getting welcome message in emulator and after that if i type "hi" OAuth Card  has to display but i am getting "A task was cancelled error".

Note: I had enabled(checked checkbox) emulator settings like "sign verification code for OAuth Cards" and "By pass ngrok for local address"

What is wrong in code?

Answer (score 2):

What version of the emulator are you using? [There is a bug in the currently released version of the V4.2.xxx emulator that blocks the OAuth emulation feature entirely](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1212). This is fixed if you use *preview* releases right now and should be fixed when 4.3.xxx is officially released.

A work around for now is to actually use the V3 version of the emulator where this functionality should work as it always did.